# hibernate one-to-many save to database

Tags: java, hibernate

Im currently working with `Hibernate` and `Java`, im trying to persist objects in our database. We have a `Group` class and a `ToDoList` class. `Group` has a one-to-many relationship with `ToDoList` as show in this [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V80gX.jpg).

The relevant code from the `Group` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Group", catalog = "db")
public class Group implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int id;
    private Set<ToDoList> allToDoLists;

    public Group(){
        allToDoLists = new HashSet<ToDoList>(0);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Group_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
    public Set<ToDoList> getAllToDoLists() {
        return this.allToDoLists;
    }

    public void addTodoList(ToDoList t){
        this.allToDoLists.add(t);
        t.setGroup(this);
    }

    public void setAllToDoLists(Set<ToDoList> allToDoLists) {
        this.allToDoLists = allToDoLists;
    }
}
```

The relevant code from the `ToDoList` class:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Todo_List", catalog = "db")
public class ToDoList {
    private int id;
    private Group group;

    public ToDoList(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Todo_List_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Group", nullable = false)
    public Group getGroup() {
        return this.group;
    }
    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

The code where the problem occurs:

```
ToDoList toDoList = new ToDoList("TodoList1","Iets","24-06-2015","24-06-2015");
Group group = new Group("Groep 1","10-11-2011","10-11-2011");
GroupDao groupDao = new GroupDaoImpl();
groupDao.store(group);
toDoList.setGroup(group);
toDoListDao.store(toDoList);
```

The code in 'groupDao' and 'toDoListDao' for storing are basicly the same:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(toDoList);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

**Problem**
When I try to store the ToDoList I get the following error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group, Name) values ('2015-06-24', '2015-06-24', 'Iets', 23, 'TodoList1')' at line 1
```

**Needed**
It whould be best if I could store `Group` and `ToDoList` whould be save also.
Given our coming deadline it whould also suffice if I can store `Group` and `ToDoList` on their own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Group" is an SQL keyword ("group by"). As such it is not the best choice of table name. It looks like this is causing conflicts given that Hibernate is generating SQL not accepted by the DBMS.

If you can't change the table name, you can probably solve that conflict by quoting the name in your entity, like so:

```
@Table(name = "`Group`", catalog = "db")
```

or

```
@Table(name = "\"Group\"", catalog = "db")
```

---

EDIT:

And as **ug_** informs me, you can also set the following hibernate property in your persistence.xml file to do that by default to all identifiers:

```
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true" />
```

I have never used that myself, but the Javadocs confirm that this is indeed a supported property:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html

Comment: You can also use the hibernate property `<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true" />` to make Hibernate quote it for you.

Comment: @ug_ I added that to the answer.